# How to show selected item different in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native's picker to pick an item from the list of items. What I want to ask is how can I make the selected item to look different may be with a different style or with an icon?

Answer (score 0):

You can use library to get such functionality, Please take a look...

http://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#picker-with-icon-style-headref

[image: It look like this]

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Header, Content, Icon, Picker, Form } from "native-base";
class PickerWithIconStyle extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selected: "key1"
    };
  }
  onValueChange(value: string) {
    this.setState({
      selected: value
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Content>
          <Form>
            <Picker
              mode="dropdown"
              iosHeader="Select your SIM"
              iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-dropdown-circle" style={{ color: "#007aff", fontSize: 25 }} />}
              style={{ width: undefined }}
              selectedValue={this.state.selected}
              onValueChange={this.onValueChange.bind(this)}
            >
              <Picker.Item label="Wallet" value="key0" />
              <Picker.Item label="ATM Card" value="key1" />
              <Picker.Item label="Debit Card" value="key2" />
              <Picker.Item label="Credit Card" value="key3" />
              <Picker.Item label="Net Banking" value="key4" />
            </Picker>
          </Form>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```